# When does IntelliJ's Scala incremental compilation happen?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, incremental-compiler

When does IntelliJ's Scala incremental compilation happen? I notice that making changes to a file does not cause the corresponding .class files (in /target) to be updated. When does this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how Scala incremental compilation works.

There are 2 different things that might be called "IntelliJ's Scala incremental compilation ":

1) Proper Scala incremental compilation which is more or less a set of typcial strategies applicable for different programming languages to not (re-)compile everythings from the scratch again when you hit Compile button. The main idea behind that is that the build system might notice that certain files and all their dependency haven't changed since the last compilation and thus you don't have to re-compile them and can use result of the last compilation instead. Those heuristics are actually complicated for Scala as it is a complicated language. Some ideas on what can be done are described at the SBT document ["Understanding Incremental Recompilation"](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Understanding-incremental-recompilation.html). At some point JetBrains decided that they are smarter and implemented their set of heuristics and they claim that they are better (i.e. incremental compilation is faster) so now you chose between SBT-based and Idea-based incremental compilation under Scala Compiler settings. But still it only works when you hit Compile (or Run or Debug or something similar). This not something Idea does in background.

2) There is another thing specific for IntelliJ Idea that also requires a kind of incremental recompilation and this one works in almost real time. It is the synxtax highlighting feature that is implemented by Idea's Scala plugin and it requires immediate re-processing of all the files you change in a way similar but now exactly the same as what the real compiler does. And actually you are not supposed to look into the details of that process (unless you are going to develop Scala plug-in itself). What those process provides is some syntax structure of the code but not the actual `.class` files.