# How to configure IntelliJ Scala Plugin to use Scala's native presentation compiler?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scala-compiler

Although [IntelliJ Scala Plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-scala) uses Scala compiler proper to generate the actual bytecode, it seems to use [its own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43083363/5205022) implementation of [presentation compiler](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206640235-Latest-Scala-IDE-for-Eclipse-uses-new-compiler-interface) to provide real-time [type-aware error highlighting](https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2011/03/02/type-aware-highlighting/) in the editor:

> syntax highlighting feature that is implemented by Idea's Scala
>   plugin and it requires immediate re-processing of all the files you
>   change in a way similar but now exactly the same as what the real
>   compiler does.

This might be the reason why sometimes projects build successfully and yet IntelliJ shows false positive red underlines in the editor. This seems to be the case even if [use sbt shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49213653/5205022) is selected as evident by open ticket [SCL-11079](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11079)

> By default, the sbt compile should mark additional errors it finds in
>   the editor and project view. False positive errors reported by the
>   internal annotator should be removed if possible. There should be an
>   option to use sbt output as the "single source of truth" for
>   highlighting errors, at the cost of instant error highlighting.

or if project is imported as [BSP project](https://gitter.im/JetBrains/intellij-scala?at=5bc49369435c2a518eae8bf2)

> sbt shell indeed won't help with error highlighting in the editor, nor
>   will BSP (for the time being). In-ide highlighting uses a method that
>   is completely separate from regular compilation

Is there anyway to configure IntelliJ to use Scala out-of-the-box [presentation compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468367/what-is-scala-presentation-compiler) instead of its own custom implementation such that we can decrease the chance false positive errors akin to what [Metals](https://scalameta.org/metals/docs/editors/overview.html) provides?

Answer (score 4):

According to [show bsp diagnostics in editor SCL-16610](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-16610) there exists a IntelliJ registry flag

```
scala.highlighting.compiler.errors.in.editor
```

which enables [experimental](https://gitter.im/JetBrains/intellij-scala?at=5e9031e05d148a0460f8caa4) feature

> As error highlighting using the built-in parser and type-checker
>   continues to be a problem for the Scala plugin, we can experiment with
>   using compiler output from BSP... Potential downsides: Less rich error highlighting on type mismatch
>   problems: BSP and the compiler expose only raw string messages and
>   positions. We would lose type diffs and type error hints.

Here are the steps that made it work on my machine

1. Install [JetBrains Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) which enables installation of *Early Access Programs* alongside releases (such that you can revert to your working system if anything goes wrong)
2. Install [2020.1](https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2020/04/09/intellij-scala-plugin-2020-1-scala-3-function-literal-highlighting-unused-parameter-inspection-smart-step-into-and-bsp-support-improvements/)
3. Make sure `Nightly Builds` update channel is set under `Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Scala | Updates`

   [image]
4. Remove `.idea` from the root of the project: `rm -fr .idea`
5. Re-import the project and select BSP project

   [image]
6. There should be `.bloop` directory under project root if all OK
7. Open IntelliJ registry: `Help | Find Action... | Registry`
8. Set key `scala.highlighting.compiler.errors.in.editor`

   [image]